# How do I install NPM Packages on an FTP-Server? (Specifically Facebook JS-SDK v2.11)

Tags: javascript, server, facebook-javascript-sdk, npm-install, node-modules

I’m trying to install https://github.com/facebook/facebook-nodejs-ads-sdk/ on my server and use the API. I downloaded the GIT-Clone and just copied the files in. Then in a PHP file I have something like:

```js
require('./js/facebook-nodejs-ads-sdk');

var FB = fb.FacebookAdsApi;
FB.init('######');
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.5/require.min.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  This is a test Page.
  </body>
</html>
```

(The HTML part obviously comes first.)
I suspect I’m doing a number of things wrong:

1. in terms of folder architecture (where I place the SDK)
2. implementing the `require(·)` statement (Require complains that I should be using require([…]), but that’s complete nonsense: according to the SDK-description, I **should** be able to write code like this:

```js
// instantiating an object
const adsSdk = require('facebook-nodejs-ads-sdk');
const AdAccount = adsSdk.AdAccount;
const account = new AdAccount(accountId);
console.log(account.id) // fields can be accessed as properties
```

I suspect I need to run a full blown installation of npm on my server. *I would ideally like to avoid this*, but if need be, then I’m prepared to do so. Only in this respect, I did not make much progress. I tried following the instructions on the npm website, but that just confused the matter.

Hence my question: is there a compact solution here? If not how do I properly install a node/npm module/package/sdk on a server?

Many thanks in advance for helpful tips.

Comment: Do you actually have a PHP file with NodeJS code?

Comment: Yeah, but I also plan to run a headerless script at some point, at that stage it will be run from Google Drive, and I’ll have to use Fetch to load scripts. I’m not even sure if that’s possible. But for now I want to get it working on the server. To clarify. I am prepared to run things client side for now.

Comment: Is there a way to take npm packages and convert them into 1 minified script?